# How to additional personal information in moderncv banking classic modified

Tags: titles, moderncv

The result should be as shown here:
[image: this picture]

```
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}  
\birthdate{07 June 2014}  <============ adding this line.
\addresss{}{}
```

but my TeX code at the bottom doesn't produce this. Can anyone see the problem?

```
%% Edited preamble

\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\@birthdate{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
% optional maketitle width to force a certain width (if set to 0pt, the width is calculated automatically)
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\makeatother
```

the working tex document:

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

%% Edited premable

\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\@birthdate{#1}}
%\newcommand*{\emailtwo}[1]{\def\@emailtwo{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
% optional maketitle width to force a certain width (if set to 0pt, the width is calculated automatically)
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% personal data
\name{John}{\underline{Doe}}
\title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\birthdate{26 June 1989}
%\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty

\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{asdf@gmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{Class 3 Driving License}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[70pt][0.1pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{To use my ability and knowledge to provide contributions that will lead to the growth and success of your company.}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That is **not** minimal! Please do read the link @ChristianHupfer posted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the line<sup>*</sup>

```
\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
```

between the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair.

[image]

<sub><sup>*</sup> Note that I've added `\def` to the replacement text for `\birthdate`, otherwise there would be no definition stored to use in the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) title.</sub>